# Is my HashSet deleting a column in my output csv file?

Tags: java, csv

So everything is showing correctly in my Java IDE and runs as it should. I have it where the data automatically writes to the csv file every few minutes. The problem I'm having is that the "Meter 2" column is not showing up and I have a feeling that the HashSet in my code might think that it's a duplicate and deleting it.

Here's the code:

```
package HourMeter;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Hours {
Set<String> hour = new HashSet<>();
String filename;
/**
 * @param filename filename of the .csv file to update
 * @param addresses Array of Strings of addresses to add to the .csv file
 * @throws IOException Throws exception on incorrect filename
 */
public Hours(String filename, String[] addresses) throws IOException {
    if(filename==null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    this.filename = filename;
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
FileReader("Hours.csv"))) {
            while(reader.ready())
            {
                hour.add(reader.readLine());
            }
        }

    if(addresses != null)
    {
                hour.addAll(Arrays.asList(addresses));
    }
}

Hours(String string) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To 
change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

public void outputFile() throws IOException
{
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("Hours.csv")) {
            hour.forEach((s) -> {
                out.println(s);
            });
        }   
}
}
```

Below is a photo of the program and the csv report.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the csv report is missing a set of string values, meter 2. What should I think about doing or changing in my code to make this show in the csv report? Thanks for the help. I have been trying to figure this out for a few days now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please include image in the question itself, also if by looking roughly it seems hashset is causing the issue, did you consider using the arraylist instead, which allows duplicate values ?

Comment: I couldn't embed the images since I'm a new user. I thought of that but the thing is, it shouldn't mistaken it for a duplicate value in the first place? Do you know an easy way to write it up in an array list similar to the one I already have written out?

Comment: just change this `Set<String> hour = new HashSet<>();` to `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>()`.

Comment: This code will ignore duplicate *rows*, but it won't remove columns. There is no column processing here. NB `ready()` is not a test for end of stream: see the Javadoc.

Comment: Amit Khandelwal, that didn't work. EJP could you elaborate a bit more on the NB ready() ? I'm fairly new to java.

Comment: Basically, don't use `ready()` - call `readLine()` until that returns null. A common loop is `while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { /* use line here */ }`

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks for commenting. I have tried that but the data gets overwritten every time inside of the csv file instead of just collecting it. Also, the meter 2 value is still missing and it has a null on top of Server. Anything else besides readLine?

Comment: It seems to me like you should really be using a debugger at this point. You may well have several separate problems, which you should try to investigate separately.

Comment: I don't have to 'elaborate' on `Reader.ready()`. It is you who has to justify your usage. What it does is specified in the Javadoc, and it doesn't say anything there about end of stream. Read and learn.

Comment: @EJP okay, thanks.